# byobu - status fields not hiding when I/O becomes zero - bug, or as expected?

Tags: byobu

I wanted to make use of byobu's "network" and "diskio" status fields, but I'm not sure if the following behaviour (#2) is normal, or buggy:

1. When there is IO, the network and disk status numbers fluctuate and report as expected.
2. When the IO stops, those numbers show the last set of numbers that were reported, indefinitely.

I was under the impression that #2 should have been "when the IO stops, and 3 seconds have elapsed, the network and diskio status numbers should disappear from the byobu status area" -- since byobu's manual states:

> network - instantaneous upload/download bandwidth in [GMk]bps over the last 3 seconds; nothing is displayed if traffic is 0;

Can anyone shed some light on this mystery - is it working as it should, or is it a bug?

Comment: This was a bug at one point.  Can you check you version of Byobu with 'byobu -v'?  I expect that this is fixed in the most recent versions.

Comment: Yep, a buggy version.  That's what I got for installing it out of Ubuntu 12.04's repositories.  I wonder how to get the Ubuntu people to update their pre-packaged byobu to a version that no longer has this bug... Interestingly, doing a "-v" with the 5.33 version somehow spits out 3 issues now "ulimit: Illegal option -u" and "[: -ge: unexpected operator" and "WARNING: ulimit -u is too low" -- I suppose they're of little consequence, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/998202) present in [Byobu](http://byobu.co) versions prior to the 4.33 release, which fixed these.

You can install newer versions from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~byobu/+archive/ppa) using:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:byobu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f byobu
```

*-- Dustin Kirkland, author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Answer (score 0):

The original author's (Dustin Kirkland) insight, I've managed to come to know that my version of byobu (5.17) was buggy, and that getting the latest version from the ppa service (5.33) resolved it.

***Debian byobu upgrade, official method***

The official method to upgrade byobu is actually to use some sort of "Debian unstable" repository: https://answers.launchpad.net/byobu/+question/184981

***Debian byobu upgrade, roughshot PPA install***:

```
sudo wget http://blog.anantshri.info/content/uploads/2010/09/add-apt-repository.sh.txt -O /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
# Followed by the "Ubuntu" commands below
```

Note: obviously, installing Ubuntu packages into Debian is at-your-own-risk. This happened to have worked out on my TurnKeyLinux system, based on Debian 6.0

***Ubuntu***:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F430BBA5
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:byobu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install byobu
```